# Trying to push a raw object to an array, and find its index later

Tags: javascript, object, canvas

I have created my own addEventListener to work with objects on a canvas, but I am having trouble making my own removeEventListener function.

In my shape constructor, I have this code:

```
this.addEventListener = function(method, func)
{
    if (method == "mouseDown")
    {
        scene.mouseDownShapes.push({shape:this, func:func})
    }
}
this.removeEventListener = function(method, func)
{
    if (method == "mouseDown")
    {
        scene.mouseDownShapes.splice(scene.mouseDownShapes.indexOf({shape:this, func:func}), 1);
    }
}
```

In my mouse down handler, I run through scene.mouseDownShapes and check if they collide with the mouse. If they do, then I call func. The problem here is, "scene.mouseDownShapes.indexOf(...)" returns -1, so it doesn't work. How do I find the index of a raw object in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object equality with `.indexOf()` only works for the same physical object (it does not work for a different object that has the same properties).

Since you don't have a reference to the same physical object that you put in the array, what you can do is to search the array for an object that has the property `shape: this`.  This involves iterating through the array to find it.

```
this.removeEventListener = function(method, func) {
    if (method == "mouseDown"){
        for (var i = 0; i < scene.mouseDownShapes.length) {
            if (scene.mouseDownShapes[i].shape === this) {
                scene.mouseDownShapes.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks!